# Knowledge And Article Management Tab Visibility Deployment

Tags: profile, knowledge, package, articles

I have enabled Lightning Knowledge post which I see two entries for Knowledge Tab Visibility in UI as highlighted below

[image: Knowledge Tab Visibility]

While I see only one Entry for knowledge Tab Visibility under the Admin.profile file.

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>Knowledge__kav</tab>

</tabVisibilities>
```

I have the following questions:

> The single tabVisibility Entry for knowledge__kav refers to the which
>   of the highlighted tabs in the picture. And if I have to deploy the
>   same visibility how do I make both Knowledge Tabs(Standard and Custom)
>   Default On.
>
> I also need to deploy Article Management Tab Visibility. However I am
>   unable to locate any such entry in profile file by which I can deploy the tab visibility of Article Management.

My Package.xml looks like following

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
</types>
 <types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Account</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomTab</name>
</types>
<version>44.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The single tabVisibility Entry for knowledge__kav refers to the which of the highlighted tabs in the picture.

It refers to the Standard Tab Settings in your screenshot. Standard [Knowledge Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soap_intro.htm) end with `__kav`.

---

> And if I have to deploy the same visibility how do I make both Knowledge Tabs(Standard and Custom) Default On.

You will need to add the entry for tab visibility as below in your profile metadata xml. Check [`ProfileTabVisibility`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm) section on the metadata documentation.

```
<tabVisibilities>
    <tab>tab-name</tab>
    <visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
</tabVisibilities>
```

---

> I also need to deploy Article Management Tab Visibility. However I am unable to locate any such entry in profile file by which I can deploy the tab visibility of Article Management.

It depends what you see on your tabs Article or Knowledge. Take a look at [Articles or Knowledge Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_articles.htm&type=5) help article to determine that. You can also refer to this article [How do I configure the Articles and Article Management tabs to appear?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005402&type=1) for details around this topic. If applicable you will again need to add the Article related entries in your profile's metadata to set the tab visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. However I haven't still understood. I already have tabVisibility for standard Knowledge tab in the form                                                ...<tab>Knowledge__kav</tab>...                                                                     
 What should I add as the tab-name for the Custom Tab . (Knowledge /Knowledge__c are not working). Also for Article Management Tab Visibility I don't understsand what tab-name should be added in the profile file.

Comment: You will need to find out the tab name for the custom object. I am not exactly sure what the tab name is for article management. The easiest way would be to configure this using UI and then fetch the metadata on the profile to see what is retrieved. You can then take it from there. Refer to the linked articles in the answer which provides direction on it.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure out the way to deploy tab visibilities for the three knowledge related tabs.

> For the standard Article Management tab, I used the following

```
<tabVisibilities>
<tab>standard-KnowledgePublishing</tab>
<visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
```

> For the standard Knowledge Tab :

```
<tabVisibilities>
<tab>standard-Knowledge</tab>
<visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
```

> And for the Custom Knowledge Tab , it remains:

```
<tabVisibilities>
<tab>Knowledge__kav</tab>
<visibility>DefaultOn</visibility>
```

However some questions are still unanswered:

- On fetching the profile details in eclipse, tab visibility details
  for Article Management and Standard Knowledge Tab is not available.

  I had to manually add the nodes in the profile file and save to server which 
  did work. Also these details again were not available in the profile file 
  after once getting successfully saved.
- For fetching details of standard tabs (say Account) in the profile file , one has to explicitly include Account under 
  the CustomObject definition in Package.xml file.

  But for Article Management and Standard Knowledge Tab I did not have anything 
  like this
- Also why do we have two separate tabs for Knowledge.